# The matrix records the last values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix .. but I don't know why you keep the last values

ِprogramme :

```
Name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
sinBox = {}
floor = {}
i=0

for k in range(3):
        for name in Name:
                i = i + 1
                sinBox[name] = i
        floor[k] = sinBox

print(floor)
```

Result :

```
{0: {'a': 13, 'b': 14, 'c': 15, 'd': 16, 'e': 17, 'f': 18}, 1: {'a': 13, 'b': 14, 'c': 15, 'd': 16, 'e': 17, 'f': 18}, 2: {'a': 13, 'b': 14, 'c': 15, 'd': 16, 'e': 17, 'f': 18}}
```

The result I want, preferably in this way, with these variables:

```
Name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

sinBox = {}

floor = {}

{0: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}, 1: {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9, 'd': 10, 'e': 11, 'f': 12}, 2: {'a': 13, 'b': 14, 'c': 15, 'd': 16, 'e': 17, 'f': 18}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit different to your approach, but you could refactor your code (as shown below) a bit to get rid of the `sinBox` variable (as well as an additional for loop) which is causing problems in your code.

```
Name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
floor = {}

for k in range(3):
  num = [k*len(Name)+i+1 for i in range(len(Name))]
  floor[k] = dict(zip(Name, num))

print(floor)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this method seems complicated .. it worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

Define `sinBox` inside the loop, or else all occurrences point to the same memory location.

```
for k in range(3):
        sinBox = {}
        for name in Name:
                i = i + 1
                sinBox[name] = i
        floor[k] = sinBox
```

Comment: Thank you .. I tried it and it gave me good results .. But in my program sinBox it is a global variable

Comment: You can use a temporary variable instead of ```sinBox```, outside the loop it wouldn't make any difference

Comment: Yes, my friend, I tried it and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @RachidBenabdelmalek Unrelated, but unless you have a very good reason to, don't use global variables. [Global variables are _evil_!](//stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953)

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi..Yes sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copy` library to make a copy of your object, which will be in a new memory location. This will also work for global variables (though the copy will be local).

```
from copy import copy

for k in range(3):
    for name in Name:
            i = i + 1
            sinBox[name] = i
    floor[k] = copy(sinBox)
```